# zoom in and out an imageview without moving it

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I was looking for a way to zoom in and out an imageview and it worked but the problem is that the image is moving when anyone drage it and it can disappear from the screen, and I want the image to be static when the user zoom it in or out.

I tried this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ZoomInZoomOut extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                            mode = DRAG;
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                            mode = NONE;
                                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                            oldDist = spacing(event);
                                            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                            if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                midPoint(mid, event);
                                                mode = ZOOM;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                            }
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                            if (mode == DRAG) 
                                            { 
                                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                            } 
                                            else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                            { 
                                                // pinch zooming
                                                float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                {
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                // zoom out
                                                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
 * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 */

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
    {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
    {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to be using a ScaleGestureRecognizer rather than trying to manually decipher the touch events. it will cleanly seperate scrolls (when the user intends to pan around) from pinches (when the user is trying to zoom) and will ignore the movement then.

see http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#scale

in that case it's scaling the canvas during draw, but that should translate relatively easily to the setImageMatrix.